# When should I set the signal mask of a threaded program in C?

Tags: c, pthreads, signals

I am working on implementing some signal handling in my P-threaded C code. I am using the RTS signal extensions. Do I need to set the mask one time for the entire process, if I want the signals to be handled the exact same way across all threads, or do I still need to call pthread_sigmask in each thread?

Also, there was some existing code that did the following:

Got an empty set, and added the SIGHUP signal

Called pthread_sigmask on that set with SIG_BLOCK

Added 4 more signals to the set 
called pthread_sigmask with SIG_UNBLOCK

does that have any effect at all, other than the last pthread_sigmask call, which set the mask to the complement of the set with the 5 signals added to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The signal mask of thread A is inherited to any thread created by thread A.